# Defining a function only once. How to?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I check to see if NS.ajax exists.  If so I do not need to redefine it.  If it does not exist I redefine it.

I want to verify that this does what I think it does and I don't waste time interpreting the function below if I already have NS.ajax defined.

NS.ajax is the same as the anonymous function seen below.

Can someone verify?

```
/*ajax
**
**
**
*/
$P.ajax = (function () {
    if (NS.ajax) {
        return NS.ajax;
    }
    return function (config) {
        var xhr;
        if (config.type === 'get') {
            xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', config.url, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    if (this.status === 200) {
                        config.callback(xhr.responseText);
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.send(null);
            return;
        }
    };
}());
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: This will set `$P.ajax` to a function.  If `NS.ajax` exist that will be returned, otherwise an anonymous function will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
$P.ajax = NS.ajax || (function () {
...
});
```

Comment: @pure_code: just FYI - when the `||` operator evaluates, it returns the first _truthy_ value it finds and stops evaluating further.  `undefined` is _falsey_, so if NS.ajax in `undefined` it continues to evaluate the right-hand-side of the `||` and finds the function definition, which is _truthy_, and returns it.

Comment: That's correct!  It returns the whole _truthy_ value (the function) rather that a boolean representing it's _truthy-ness_.  This is what you want, I just thought I'd try to explain what's happening :)

Answer (score 1):

You can return `NS.ajax` or your own function in the same line.

```
return NS.ajax || function (config) {...
```